# MediaWiki: Allowing users to create accounts on a private wiki

Tags: mediawiki, user-permissions

I've set up a private wiki for a class, and I'd like the students to create their own accounts (saving me from having to manually create them and email them instructions on how to login). 
In LocalSettings.php, I changed the settings to the following:

```
# The following permissions were set based on your choice in the installer
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
```

My intention is for anyone to create an account (I can add the ConfirmAccount extension if need be, but more likely I'll just change the flag to false after my students have signed up), but nobody can read or edit pages without becoming a user.

On the main page of the wiki, there is now a link to Create Account.  However, clicking it just leads back to the Login prompt.  The only way I can get the Create Account page is by changing all of the permissions above to true.

Is there a way to block read/edit access but allow account creation?

Answer (score 2):

Okay I found a solution--surprising this wasn't included in the mediawiki documentation on the pages for managing users or restricting access.

Add this line to LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgWhitelistRead = array( 'Special:RequestAccount', 'Main Page', 'Special:CreateAccount' );
```

Comment: Really? It's, like, the second code line in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Simple_private_wiki Where did you look? :)